# In Xcode with git, can you merge one branch with only changes after a certain date to master?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, merge

all,

I have two branches, one is master, one is client and we have made a lot of changes in the client branch. Now we know all changes in client branch we made before 1/1/2015 are good and need to be merged into master. How do I do that? (Of course we also made a lot changes after 1/1/2015 in client).

What I did in Xcode 6.1 is switch to branch Client, then click Source Control -> Client -> Merge Into Branch -> Master, however looks like that is going to merge everything from client to master, not just the ones before 1/1/2015.

Another option might be, revert my code to the last change set status before 1/1/2015 in Client, then merge it back to master? Will that work, if it does, how do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI - using `git` from the command line lets you do a lot more than you can through Xcode. And a Google search will give you many results on how to do various types of merges using `git`.

Comment: You can retroactively make a branch to solve this. Point the branch at the 1/1/2015 commit before which all commits are good and should be merged. Merge that branch. Bingo bango Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Have you considered a tool such as SourceTree? While Xcode is decent for standard pull, commit, push, workflow, I prefer sourcetree for managing merges/branching and other gitflow operations simply because it gives you dedicated view of what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -b newbranch $(git rev-list oldbranch --before=1.1.2015 -1)
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff newbranch
```

You could also use the reflog date like this,

```
git checkout -b newbranch oldbranch@{1/1/2015}
```

if you were the only one to commit this branch, and your reflogs are still working.